# Как вычислить координаты второй точки гипотенузы, если известны её длина и угол?

Tags: python, математика, тригонометрия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как определить координаты точки "?" ?

Comment: Координаты нельзя вычислить без указания системы координат, в которой находится данная фигура

Comment: Для данной диаграммы координаты второй точки равны длинам катетов. Длины катетов вычисляются как синус и косинус угла помноженный на длину гипотенузы (противолежащий катет - синус, прилежащий - косинус). Единственно, если ось Y направлена вверх, то координата y будет равна длине катета с минусом.

Answer (score 4):

Если верхняя вершина (0,0), вертикальный катет — ось OY, направленная вверх (так что ось OX направлена вправо), длина гипотенузы *L*, а угол α, то при таких условиях

x<sub>?</sub> =  *L**sin(α)
y<sub>?</sub> = -*L**cos(α)

Если подразумеваются ***не*** эти условия, то надо точно указать, какие.

Впрочем, это требуется в любом случае, просто математическая культура требует...

Answer (score -1):

Сначала найти начало гипотенузы (например, начало координат или координаты одного из вершин треугольника). Потом координаты конца гипотенузы с помощью длины гипотенузы и угла.Начало и конец гипотенузы теперь есть, поэтому можно определить уравнение прямой, проходящей через эти точки.

Comment: Вопрос исходный был, _**как вычислить координаты второй точки гипотенузы**_, ваш ответ не по существу.

Comment: @NowhereMan до моей правки заголовок был "Как вычислить координаты точек гипотенузы, если известны её длина и угол?", так что можно было понять вопрос как "как вычислить координаты всех точек", но похоже у автора сложность просто с получением координат второй точки.

Comment: @insolor, из рисунка понятно, что одна из точек -- в начале координат.  В любом случае данная попытка не содержит ответа по существу.